# Provisioning a docker image with chef

Tags: docker, chef-infra, berkshelf

I am trying to build a docker image that is provisioned with chef. It works for me with the following Dockerfile and chef recipe.

```
#Dockerfile
FROM centos:7
RUN yum install -y wget
RUN wget https://packages.chef.io/stable/el/7/chefdk-0.13.21-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
RUN yum install -y chefdk-0.13.21-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
COPY cookbooks cookbooks
RUN cd cookbooks/hs_price_verification && berks install && berks vendor cookbooks && chef-client -z --override-runlist hs_price_verification

#default.rb
include_recipe 'git'
package 'yum-utils'
execute 'yum --enablerepo=base clean metadata'
execute 'yum update -y || true'
execute 'yum-config-manager --enable cr'
domain=node['domainsname']
```

However if I move chef-client command to its own RUN line in the Dockerfile

```
...
RUN cd cookbooks/hs_price_verification && berks install && berks vendor cookbooks
RUN chef-client -z --override-runlist hs_price_verification
```

I get an error

```
================================================================================
Error Resolving Cookbooks for Run List:
================================================================================

Missing Cookbooks:
------------------
No such cookbook: git
```

Its like the results of 'berks install && berks vendor cookbooks' is on available on the same line of the Dockerfile and when I move the command the 'cache' is lost.

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker runs each `RUN` line in its own command, this means that the `cd` from the line before has no effect there.